# every time i run an program i get error: there is an error in your program: expected an indented bloak

Tags: python

```
    #
import swampy
    from swampy.TurtleWorld import *
    world = TurtleWorld()
    bob = Turtle()
    def polygon(t, n, length):
    angle = 360.0 / n
    for i in range(n):
    fd(t, length)
    lt(t, angle) 
    polygon(bob, 7, 70)
```

expected an indented bloak
every time i run program i get this error

Comment: So, what's your question? It tells you that you need to indent; why don't you?

Comment: This is because python cares about indentation unlike other languages. https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html

Comment: You need to left shift all your lines from line 2. There should not be any space . Read about python basics in some document and then start programs

Comment: as a beginner in python i have no hint about this error, so can u explain it...? and what was wrong in my program..? there is any missing statement

Comment: Ladies and Gentlemen, this human is about to quit Python because they don't like indentation. Thank you.

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to write Python without even having learnt the first thing about it? Start withe the link in@Zack Tarr's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Try running this code:

```
import swampy
from swampy.TurtleWorld import *
world = TurtleWorld()
bob = Turtle()
def polygon(t, n, length):
    angle = 360.0 / n
    for i in range(n):
        fd(t, length)
        lt(t, angle) 
polygon(bob, 7, 70)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking so much and you're not understanding so I'll try here...

Python is a programming language that; unlike other languages actually cares about indentation inside the code. This means that all things you write must be indented correctly otherwise it will throw an error at you.

In your code you have indented parts where you don't need indentation and you have no indentation where you need it. Here is the correctly indented code:

```
import swampy
from swampy.TurtleWorld import *
world = TurtleWorld()
bob = Turtle()
def polygon(t, n, length):
    angle = 360.0 / n
    for i in range(n):
        fd(t, length)
        lt(t, angle) 
polygon(bob, 7, 70)
```

Here it is clear that your base code has no indents but as soon as you define your function it gets indented to show that anything else indented in the same way is part of the function. This is the same with your for loop: Anything indented with your for loop is part of your for loop. That's why the function call isn't also looped.

To also add, indentation is considered because there are no calls to end the loop or end a function like VB.NET for example. In VB.NET, you have a start of the function and you can call the end.